# How do i make my footer stay at the bottom of my page in CSS without overlapping

Tags: html, css, background, footer, overlapping

Hi i'm new to learning HTML/CSS, i'm currently struggling to see why my footer is overlapping my webpage, i've tried to use postion: fixed; & bottom:0; to keep it at the bottom but that's not working , the answer is probably obvious to someone, i'll appreciate any help on this, see my html/css code below.

Image of webpage > https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOX3m.jpg

HTML

```
<body>
    <section class="slider">
        <ul class="slider-carousel" id="slider-carousel">

            <li class="img1">
                <h2>Slider<span>Slider</span></h2>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-android"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-windows"></i>
                <p><br>Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod.Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel po rttitor in, auctor et sapien.<br> Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa
                </p><br>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-full">Lets Go</a>
            </li>


            <li class="img2">
                <h2>Slider<span>Slider</span></h2>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-android"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-windows"></i>
                <p><br>Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod.Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel po rttitor in, auctor et sapien.<br> Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa
                </p><br>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-full">Lets Go</a>
            </li>


            <li class="img3">
                <h2>Slider<span>Slider</span></h2>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-android"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-windows"></i>
                <p><br>Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod.Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel po rttitor in, auctor et sapien.<br> Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa
                </p><br>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-full">Lets Go</a>
            </li>

        </ul>



    <div class="login-box">
            <h1>Login</h1>

            <div class="textbox">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
            </div>


       <div class="textbox">
           <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">
            </div>

            <input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign In">


             </div>
    </section>


    <footer>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Log In</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">My Surveys</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
     <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
```

CSS

```
  }

body{
    height:100%;
    background-color:black !important;
}

/*-------------header-----------*/


header
{
    height:110px;
    line-height: 110px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
}

.secondary{
    background-color:darkorange;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 15px 0px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/*-------------nav-----------*/


ul
{
    list-style:none;

}

ul li
{
    display:inline-block;

}

header nav
{
    float: right;
}

.logo img
{
    margin-top:25px;
}

header nav ul li a 
{
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

header nav ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}

/*-------------slider-----------*/


.img1
{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(work.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;


}

.slider,.slider ul,.slider ul li
{
    height:700px;
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0px;

}

.slider h2
{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top:260px;
}

.slider span
{
    color:orange;
}

.slider a 
{
    padding: 10px 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;

}

.slider a.btn-half

{
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
}

.slider a.btn-half:hover
{
    opacity:0.7;
    transition:0.5s ease-in;
}

.slider a.btn-full
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.slider a.btn-full:hover
{
    opacity:0.7;
    transition:0.5s ease-in;

}

.img2
{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(work2.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
}

.img3
{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(work3.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
}

.slider i
{
    font-size:30px;
    margin-right:10px;
}

/*-------------login-----------*/



.login-box
{
    width:280px;
    position:absolute;
    top:1000px;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:white;
}

.login-box h1 
{
    width:100px;
    font-size:40px;
    border-bottom: 6px solid darkorange;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    padding:13 px 0;
}

.textbox
{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:8px 0;
    margin:8px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid darkorange;
}

.textbox i 
{
    width:26px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

.textbox input
{
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    background:none;
    color:white;
    font-size:17px;
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px;
}

.btn
{
    width:100%;
    background:none;
    border:2px solid darkorange;
    color:white;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:17px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:12px 0;
}

.btn:hover
{
    opacity:0.7;
    transition:0.5s ease-in;
}

/*-------------footer-----------*/


.footer {
   width:100%;
    background-color: darkorange;
    padding:50px 0px;
    position:fixed;

}



footer nav
{
    text-align:center;
}


footer nav ul li a 
{
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

footer nav ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe the issue is with your `footer` code. It looks like your `body` content is being pushed down rather than your `footer` content being pushed up. Without the CSS, it's hard to tell for sure.

Comment: I've added my full CSS into the post apologies if it looks messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your CSS outside of the `footer`. In the selector `.slider, .slider ul, .slider ul li`, you have `height: 700px;`. Because you have 3 of these elements, it's essentially being stretched down **2100 px!** Because you have the `footer` set to `position: fixed;` it wants to stay at that position on the screen, even though there is already content there.

This is how these 2 selectors should look:

```
.slider, .slider ul, .slider ul li{
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0px;
}
footer {
    width:100%;
    background-color: darkorange;
    padding:50px 0px;
}
```

```css
body{
    height:100%;
    background-color:black !important;
}

/*-------------header-----------*/


header
{
    height:110px;
    line-height: 110px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
}

.secondary{
    background-color:darkorange;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 15px 0px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/*-------------nav-----------*/


ul
{
    list-style:none;

}

ul li
{
    display:inline-block;

}

header nav
{
    float: right;
}

.logo img
{
    margin-top:25px;
}

header nav ul li a 
{
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

header nav ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}

/*-------------slider-----------*/


.img1
{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(work.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;


}

.slider, .slider ul, .slider ul li{
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0px;
}

.slider h2
{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top:260px;
}

.slider span
{
    color:orange;
}

.slider a 
{
    padding: 10px 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;

}

.slider a.btn-half

{
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
}

.slider a.btn-half:hover
{
    opacity:0.7;
    transition:0.5s ease-in;
}

.slider a.btn-full
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.slider a.btn-full:hover
{
    opacity:0.7;
    transition:0.5s ease-in;

}

.img2
{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(work2.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
}

.img3
{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(work3.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
}

.slider i
{
    font-size:30px;
    margin-right:10px;
}

/*-------------login-----------*/



.login-box
{
    width:280px;
    position:absolute;
    top:1000px;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:white;
}

.login-box h1 
{
    width:100px;
    font-size:40px;
    border-bottom: 6px solid darkorange;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    padding:13 px 0;
}

.textbox
{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:8px 0;
    margin:8px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid darkorange;
}

.textbox i 
{
    width:26px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

.textbox input
{
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    background:none;
    color:white;
    font-size:17px;
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px;
}

.btn
{
    width:100%;
    background:none;
    border:2px solid darkorange;
    color:white;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:17px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:12px 0;
}

.btn:hover
{
    opacity:0.7;
    transition:0.5s ease-in;
}

/*-------------footer-----------*/


footer {
    width:100%;
    background-color: darkorange;
    padding:50px 0px;
}



footer nav
{
    text-align:center;
}


footer nav ul li a 
{
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

footer nav ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="slider">
        <ul class="slider-carousel" id="slider-carousel">
            <li class="img1">
                <h2>Slider<span>Slider</span></h2>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-android"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-windows"></i>
                <p><br>Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod.Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel po rttitor in, auctor et sapien.<br> Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa
                </p><br>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-full">Lets Go</a>
            </li>
            <li class="img2">
                <h2>Slider<span>Slider</span></h2>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-android"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-windows"></i>
                <p><br>Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod.Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel po rttitor in, auctor et sapien.<br> Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa
                </p><br>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-full">Lets Go</a>
            </li>
            <li class="img3">
                <h2>Slider<span>Slider</span></h2>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-android"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-windows"></i>
                <p><br>Curabitur sodales sem nec nisl finibus, nec suscipit magna euismod.Praesent nibh leo, auctor vel po rttitor in, auctor et sapien.<br> Nullam et nulla rutrum, convallis tellus vitae, eleifend massa
                </p><br>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-half">Get Started</a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-full">Lets Go</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="login-box">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div class="textbox">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">
            </div>
            <input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign In">
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Log In</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">My Surveys</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! As simple as it sounds i didn't know all 3 elements would be streched to 2100px.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, your footer has no ending tag like `</footer>`

**Second**, add class to your footer like **footer class="footer"** or maybe wrap the whole thing into a **div class="footer"** then add a .(dot) in front of the footer in css like `.footer {//something here}`
Then add clear: both property to whatever you have in your css.

```
.footer {
    width:100%;
    background-color: darkorange;
    padding:50px 0px;
    position:fixed;
    clear: both; // like this
}
```

The clear property tells on which sides of an element floating elements cannot float.

By using **both** value for clear. You can specify no element can float neither on right nor left side of the element.

**Just in case: while trying clear: both. If it didn't work change position to relative.**

Comment: Using `footer` as the selector or `.footer` and setting the tag to `footer class="footer"` is the same thing and doesn't solve the issue of the footer overlapping the content in the body.

Comment: Right now yes. but later on any other footer he wants to implement in his/her site will follow the same css rule. same as when you implement css for img. it will work. but it will be one style for all. Plus my solution is clear: both. I dont know if that explained your question.

Comment: Having different `footer` styling on different pages is not the issue. The question is in regards to the `footer` overlapping the content in the `body`.

Comment: Please read my solution. I provided the solution which is clear: both! but explaining more for future knowledge never hurts anybody ;)